# Powershell - RiskEventStatus change from powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, api

Currently I have the below script that connects to o365 Risky Users to pull users with an active risk event and pipes their username to a CSV so we can run a remediation script against their account.

https://pastebin.com/xNcvWL8h

What I was trying to figure out is if there is a way to change the RiskEventStatus from "Active" to "Closed".  I haven't really turned up any useful results to accomplish this.

Anyone have any useful information for this?

Comment: I've not personally had to do this as I manage labs, thus would not need it. Yet, if you can do it in the AAD/O365 GUI / web page, you should be able to do it in PowerShell. You have to use Get-Member to see what property you need to set.

Comment: Because this is via the API im not sure if the URI can accept an API Put to change the status.  Documentation says so but I cant figure out the syntax to do that.  I mean I can pull the status using

the $response variable but writing back is the confusing part